# Error while updating SQLite Database

Tags: java

I want to update my database where the `hotelname` = "" (the text in `EditText`). but i am getting an error in my class file and the `sqlitehelper` file for the same method {`updatedetails()`)
Where am I going wrong in this?

Here is my code: SQliteHelper class

```
   public int updatedetails(String hotelname, String city, String desc, 
   String rooms, String price, byte[] image) {

    ContentValues updateValues=new ContentValues();
    updateValues.put("hotelname", hotelname);
    updateValues.put("city", city);
    updateValues.put("desc", desc);
    updateValues.put("rooms", rooms);
    updateValues.put("price", price);
    updateValues.put("image", image);
    return db.update("Hotel_info", updateValues, "hotelname" + "=" 
    +hotelname, null);
}
```

And AdminActivity Class:

```
   sqLiteHelper.updatedetails( edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
    edtcity.getText().toString().trim(),
    edtdesc.getText().toString().trim(),
    edtrooms.getText().toString().trim(),
    edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
    imageViewToByte(imageView));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your error log

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String[] hotelname= new String[]{hotelname};

db.update("Hotel_info", updateValues, "hotelname=?" , hotelname,null);
```